# Atem Switcher SDK for iOS how to make connection with device?

Tags: ios, sdk

I have a SDK from Blackmagic https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/support/family/atem-live-production-switchers  and I want to make from my iPad aplication switching ports on the Atem Television Studio. The sample with SDK is for Mac OS and I couldn't use this to connect with Atem from my app iPad. Any idea or examples code app to do it?

```
mSwitcherMonitor = new SwitcherMonitor(self);
mMixEffectBlockMonitor = new MixEffectBlockMonitor(self);

mMoveSliderDownwards = false;
mCurrentTransitionReachedHalfway = false;

mSwitcherDiscovery = CreateBMDSwitcherDiscoveryInstance();
```

`mSwitcherMonitor = new SwitcherMonitor(self);` - is nil

`mMixEffectBlockMonitor = new MixEffectBlockMonitor(self);` - is nil

`mSwitcherDiscovery = CreateBMDSwitcherDiscoveryInstance();` - crash app

Answer (score 0):

The framework from BMD is a complied x86 C++ library. For iOS you can either write a library by yourself or find some help from internet. I don't see any library was ready to use for ios but so does for Arduino:

https://github.com/kasperskaarhoj/Arduino-Library-for-ATEM-Switchers

It is not a standard C++ library. Some pesudo method is only write for Arduino, specially socket communication part. To use in iOS, you can try to write another library (or write some bridge function for Arduino library) for that. Here's the reference:

http://skaarhoj.com/fileadmin/BMDPROTOCOL.html